# Rails 4.2 changing Garlic.js's pathnames

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, local-storage

In the Rails 4.1 version of my app my form fields are being saved to localStorage by [Garlic.js](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/garlic.js) as the following:

`garlic:www.mydomain.com/posts/new>form>input.post[title]: "d"`

Yet when I upgrade the app to Rails 4.2 these path change to:

`garlic:gsp-staging.premiacapital.com/posts/new>form>input.post[title]:eq(2) "d"`

This is causing havoc with my tests (I'm using the pathnames to test localStorage). Any idea why this `eq(2)` is being appended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit.

Basically, in all previous version of Rails the input row had no siblings:

```
[
   <input class="span12 garlic-auto-save" id="js_post_title" name="post[title]" type="text">
]
```

Whereas in Rails 4.2 the input in the form seems be accompanied by a number of other hidden input fields:

```
[
   <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓" class="garlic-auto-save">,
   <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="9I6MjfVtm76tXLI4pQjv9/yIhO8jpgg84SZcA/VZGaSkQ9vNqHoz54NYFpYeJLs9Im86hIF2qOBCPXE48YZhKw==" class="garlic-auto-save">,
   <input class="span12 garlic-auto-save" id="js_post_title" type="text" name="post[title]">
]
```

This means that [this method](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Garlic.js/blob/21572538c337862744802442d426096b0caca648/garlic.js#L320) in Garlic.js is triggered which therefore appends the `eq(2)` as a unique identifier to the end of the path name.

So I simply had to update my tests with this new unique identifier and they all passed.